# Weird problem using ANY operator in SQL query with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Let me explain my scenario.

I have a simple table with 5.5 million records. The structure is straightforward.

```
relations
------------
id
parent_id
name
```

I have a recursive function to get all the children ids of a node; that function works fine in every case. That's not the problem here.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION children_ids(id INTEGER)
RETURNS INT[]
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    ids INT[];
    r RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN WITH RECURSIVE t
    AS
    (
        SELECT * 
          FROM relations sa
         WHERE sa.id = id
         UNION ALL
        SELECT next.*
          FROM t prev
          JOIN relations next ON (next.parent_id = prev.id)
    )
    SELECT t.id FROM t
    LOOP
        ids := ids || r.id;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN ids;
END
$$;
```

Then I need to query another table to get the count of the records in any of the children ids returned by the function:

The query that I want to do is:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.*) FROM books AS p WHERE p.id = ANY(children_ids(20));
```

But it fails due to a timeout. The weird thing here is that this same query in my localhost is working fine, the databases were cloned and the PostgreSQL version is the same.

I have tested another variants and those are the result:

```
SELECT children_ids(20);
-- WORKS: {20}

SELECT COUNT(p.*) FROM books AS p WHERE p.id = ANY(children_ids(20)); 
-- FAILS: TIMEOUT

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books AS p WHERE p.id = ANY(children_ids(20)); 
-- FAILS: TIMEOUT

SELECT * FROM books AS p WHERE p.id = ANY(children_ids(20));
-- FAILS: TIMEOUT

SELECT COUNT(p.*) FROM books AS p WHERE p.id = ANY(ARRAY[20]);
-- WORKS: 0

SELECT COUNT(p.*) FROM books AS p WHERE p.id IN (20);
-- WORKS: 0

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books AS p WHERE p.id IN (20);
-- WORKS: 0
```

Any ideas of what could be happening here?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need a slow and inefficient PL/pgSQL loop to begin with.

Comment: I know, is just to create a simple query. Can you explain a simple method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a cycle in your data, so that your recursion runs into an endless loop. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-CYCLE) for how to break the cycle. With PostgreSQL v14 or better, the simplest way would be

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
   SELECT ...
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ...
) CYCLE id SET is_cycle USING path
```